# <ons-navigator>と<ons-template>を指定したアラートダイアログ

Tags: onsen-ui

ons-navigatorタグとons-templateタグを指定するとアラートダイアログが利用できません。

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJxEWN

```js
ons.bootstrap()

  .controller('NotificationController', function($scope) {
    $scope.alert = function() {
      ons.notification.alert({
        message: 'An error has occurred!'
      });
    }

    $scope.confirm = function() {
      ons.notification.confirm({
        message: 'Are you sure you want to continue?',
        callback: function(idx) {
          switch (idx) {
            case 0:
              ons.notification.alert({
                message: 'You pressed "Cancel".'
              });
              break;
            case 1:
              ons.notification.alert({
                message: 'You pressed "OK".'
              });
              break;
          }
        }
      });
    }

    $scope.prompt = function() {
      ons.notification.prompt({
        message: "Please enter your age",
        callback: function(age) {
          ons.notification.alert({
            message: 'You are ' + parseInt(age || 0) + ' years old.'
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.3/build/css/onsen-css-components.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.3/build/css/onsenui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.3/build/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.3/build/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<ons-navigator var="navigator" page="alert.html"></ons-navigator>

<ons-template id="alert.html">
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="center">
        Notifications
      </div>
    </ons-toolbar>

    <ons-list ng-controller="NotificationController">
      <ons-list-item ng-click="alert()" modifier="tappable">
        Alert
      </ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item ng-click="confirm()" modifier="tappable">
        Confirm
      </ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item ng-click="prompt()" modifier="tappable">
        Prompt
      </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
  </ons-page>
</ons-template>
```

教えてください。

Comment: リンク先を見ると動いているように思われますが、期待している動作とは異なりますか？

Comment: クリックしてもアラートダイアログが表示されません。